# Customizar ASP.NET Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

Ainda uso apenas o `FormsAuthentication` mas estou querendo migrar para o `ASP.NET Identity` em `MVC`.

Nos meus projetos atuais, não trabalho com as  `roles` do `FormsAuthentication`, e sim por permissão de acesso por `controller` e `actions` aonde salvo estes dados em uma `session` por usuário logado, por vários motivos.

Atualmente quando vou logar, eu utilizo:

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie('login@login.com', false);
```

No blog do Eduardo Pires, tem o artigo neste [link](https://www.eduardopires.net.br/2015/02/customizando-nomes-tabelas-campos-asp-net-identity/) que mostra que podemos usar o `ASP.NET Identity`com uma nomenclatura customizada e mostra que é necessário ter todas as tabelas mapeadas utilizadas no `ASP.NET Identity`.

A minhas dúvida são:

- Será que consigo mapear as tabelas usando `Data Annotations` ou terei que usar `Fluent API`?
- Como o processo atual é um cadastro normal, será que com o `ASP.NET Identity` consigo fazer o mesmo processo?

Answer (score 0):

De acordo com essa [resposta do Stackoverflow em inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5354900/entity-framework-code-first-advantages-and-disadvantages-of-fluent-api-vs-data) `Data Annotations` tem algumas limitações. Tudo o que você pode fazer com `Data Annotations` é possível com `Fluent API` não o contrário.

Se você precisar de algo muito específico tipo:

- Desativar `cascade` ao deletar dados em tabelas;
- Especificar chave primária quando não expostas na sua classe de dados;
- Casos muito específicos de granulidade nos relacionamentos de tables, especialmente quando somente uma das associações está exposta...

Aí você deve usar `Fluent API`.

`ASP.NET Identity` é uma nova versão do MembershipProvider (legado) que utiliza SignInManager e tem muito mais recursos que o legado.

Espero que te ajude minha resposta.